# All of the tabs except 1 disappeared from the Excel (365 Family) that I created yesterday

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabs, version

I created an excel yesterday with 4 or 5 tabs and spent several hours working on one of the tabs.  Today only one tab exists and it has been renamed to be the same as the file name. When I check version control it says the file was created today and it has no record of the one I created yesterday.  Same thing when I check in my One Drive Recycle Bin, the file I created and saved yesterday does not appear even though several others that I created and didn't save do appear. I have checked all the obvious things via google - e.g. the tabs are not hidden, the advanced settings do indicate that all tabs must be shown.  Is there anyway I can get back the work I did yesterday?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It sounds like you never saved the file, so it was never uploaded to OneDrive, thus there isn’t a file to recover

Comment: Yes, web oneDrive has an autosave feature. I cannot remember if desktop oneDrive (that syncs to web oneDrive) has that too, or if that syncing might have gone bad and caused your unfortunate situation. All I can suggest is to make sure autosave is on and that you are saving to the cloud rather than desktop.

Comment: Did you mean you save the file in OneDrive? Did you open it in desktop app or web?

Comment: Is it possible the file was saved as CSv format rather than Excel? You should have seen warning messages if that was the case though. And sadly it won't help you recover the file, but might help avoid the issue in future.